# Puppet contain not working to order class inclusion

Tags: puppet, erb

I am trying to force a Puppet class that creates a file to be processed *before* another class that needs this file to exist to run properly. Following the Puppet article [Language: Containment of resources](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_containment.html) I am using `contain`.

My code does not work and I do not understand why. It gives this error:

```
Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Failed to parse template testing/def.erb:
  Filepath: /root/local/testing/templates/def.erb
  Line: 1
  Detail: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/abc
 at /root/local/test2.pp:16:16 on node example.com
```

Here is the code (stripped down):

```
### test2.pp
class klass1 {
  file { '/tmp/abc':
    content => 'xxx',
  }
}

# Stage 0 creates the file /tmp/abc.
class stage0 {
  contain klass1
}

# Stage 1 uses the contents of /tmp/abc to create the
# file /tmp/def.
class stage1 {
  file { '/tmp/def':
    content => template('testing/def.erb'),
  }
}

# Try to force stage0 to be loaded before stage1.
include stage0
class { 'stage1':
  require => Class['stage0']
}

### testing/templates/def.erb
Contents: <%= File.read("/tmp/abc") %>
```

I am using Puppet 5.3.3.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here does not relate to containment, but to the dependency in your template at compile time on the call to `File.read("/tmp/abc")`.

Ordinarily, compilation occurs on the Puppet Master a.k.a. Puppet Server, and the template function also runs at this time. Thus, your template `def.erb` attempts to read from a nonexistent file at compile time on the Puppet Master.

A better solution is likely to be define the content of file `/tmp/abc` in Puppet itself as data or a variable and then pass that variable to the template function, and so remove the dependency on reading from the file on disk altogether.

Without fully understanding why you were trying to separate this file content into multiple classes in the first place, I can't really comment any further.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet is a declarative language that is typically used to ensure certain state of resources. But if you really need make a decision based on local code evaluation, you're basically left with 2 options:

Firstly, use `facter`, in some module create `lib/facter/my_fact.rb`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'facter'

Facter.add(:load1) do
  confine kernel: 'Linux'
  setcode do
    Facter::Util::Resolution.exec("cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print $1}'")
  end
end
```

Then your "function" result will be available via `facter load1` (from shell) or `$facts['load1']` from Puppet code. Such code is always evaluated before applying Puppet's catalog. If your function doesn't take arguments, this might be a good option. Note this is a silly example, the load is already available via `facter load_averages.1m` (though the usefulness of such fact is questionable). Using too many facts isn't good idea, it would prolong time  required for applying a Puppet catalog. There's a [soft limit for number of facts](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/configuration.html#number-of-facts-soft-limit) on `puppetserver`.

Second option would be using [`Deferred` function](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/deferring_functions.html). Evaluation of such function is delayed into later phase of catalog application (won't be evaluated on compile server).

Puppet code looks like this:

```
$value = Deferred("mymodule::load", ["1m"])
```

and the actual implementation should be in a Puppet module in a Ruby function, e.g. `lib/puppet/functions/load.rb`:

```
Puppet::Functions.create_function(:'mymodule::load') do
  dispatch :load do
    param 'String', :load_type
    return_type 'String'
  end

  def load(load_type)
    case load_type
    when '1m'
      avgs[0]
    when '5m'
      avgs[1]
    else
      raise "#{load_type} not supported"
    end
  end
end
```

The advantage is the latter approach is that you can pass multiple arguments. Although returning more complex types than `String` or `Numeric` doesn't seem to currently supported.

Comment: This answer provides a lot of good information, but it doesn't directly address the actual question posed (why doesn't the posted code work).  Moreover, as presented, the OP's code does not actually rely on local code evaluation.  Although it appears to be trying to consume a local file as a template, that local file's content is Puppet-managed, and therefore known on the server side.